# Java based user authentication

Tags: java, user-controls, user-accounts

Can someone point me in the direction of a good Java library to use to handle basic user login/authentication.

I am looking for a competent I can integrate into a custom app to handle simple user/name password authentication and send account validation/password reset emails.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the [JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html). Look at the user guide and to get an overview of it look at the tutorials and simple programs of this guide.

Answer (score 1):

Filters would work:
http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html